# Как сделать полноэкранный режим чтобы отображался taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf

Я знаю как сделать полноэкранный  режим,но прячет  taskbar,как это пофиксить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Моя программа** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**С# код**

```
 if (WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
   {
       window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;  
   }
   else
   {
          window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
   }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35010001/6808809

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ спасибо  **EvgeniyZ** 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009880/how-to-make-full-screen-mode-without-covering-the-taskbar-using-wpf-c-sharp/35010001#35010001

**Дополнительные источник**

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107994/Taskbar-with-Window-Maximized-and-WindowState-to-N